# Software manager

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on my NEC-Powermate vl280 along with win 7. My problem is that when I try to install something (say vlc) with software center it gets stuck and I have to force close it. This is the first time I tried to install something using Software Center. I am new to Ubuntu. what can I do to fix it?

I tried to install vlc by running the this command `sudo apt-get install vlc` in the terminal and it worked. but what about the software center?

Comment: try to install vlc by running the this command `sudo apt-get install vlc` on terminal.

Comment: ok it worked but what about the software center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Synaptic Package manager and see if you can install software that way. It is possible Synaptic is not present on your system so you'll have to install it. To do so, press Ctrl+Alt+T, to open a terminal, and type in the terminal this code:

```
 sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Enter your password when prompted and wait for the results. If synaptic it already installed, you can open it by typing **sudo synaptic** in the same terminal. You can still use Software Center to install software. With Synaptic, install a lightweight version of the software center called lubuntu-software-center. Install it and test it to see whether it works better than ubuntu software center. If it does not, then you can use Synaptic to install all the software that you need. Make sure that you also enable the **Canonical partners** and **Independent** repositories in synaptic by going to Synaptic menu - Settings - Repositories - Other Software. After you check **Canonical partners** and **Independent** close the window and reload your software list with the Reload button from Synaptic.

One other way to install software in ubuntu is to install **aptitude** package with this code in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

You can use aptitude in a terminal emulator the same way you use apt-get typing a code like:

```
sudo aptitude install <package name>
```

Comment: thanx. i will install synaptic